# Riot-tag inside of a loop

Tags: node.js, tags, riot.js

I have a `xxx` component, which when used with the `riot-tag` attribute and a standard HTML5 tag, works correctly: `<article riot-tag="xxx"></article>`. However when I use the `riot-tag` attribute inside of a loop, the tag is empty: `<article each="{xxxTags}" riot-tag="{xxx}"></article>`. Is using `riot-tag` in a loop possible at all? How can I make it work?

---

Additional explanation:

I have to generate several different, albeit similar components one by one. So I have an array to store them:

```
var xxxTags = [{tag: 'xxx'}, {tag: 'yyy'}, {tag: 'zzz'}];
```

Putting any of the `textareas` one by one manually for all of: *xxx*, *yyy*, *zzz* works fine and generates the respective components. However when I try to do it with `each`, they end up empty (no children) in chrome devtools, BUT otherwise identical to the ones put manually.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<my-tag></my-tag>

<!-- inlined tag definition -->
<script type="riot/tag">
  <my-tag>
    /*Standard, manual addition of different components (works)*/
    <xxx></xxx>
    <yyy></yyy>
    <zzz></zzz>
    /*Standard addition of same components in a loop (works)*/
    <div each={myTags}>{tag}</div>
    <br>
    /*Addition of different components with "riot-tag" manually (works)*/
    <div riot-tag="xxx"></div>
    <div riot-tag="yyy"></div>
    <div riot-tag="zzz"></div>
    /*Addition of different components with "riot-tag" in a loop (DOESN'T WORK should look like the example above)*/
    <div each={myTags} riot-tag="{tag}"></div>
    
    this.myTags = [{tag: 'xxx'}, {tag: 'yyy'}, {tag: 'zzz'}];
  </my-tag>
  
  <xxx>
    <p>X content</p>
  </xxx>
  
  <yyy>
    <p>Y content</p>
  </yyy>
  
  <zzz>
    <p>Z content</p>
  </zzz>
</script>

<!-- include riot.js and the compiler -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/riot@2.2(riot.min.js+compiler.min.js)"></script>


<!-- mount normally -->
<script>
  riot.mount('*');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, looks, like the tags with `riot-tag` attribute are not *mounted* when generated with an *each*-loop (still looks like a bug?). For the above-mentioned code, adding this does the job:

```
this.on('mount', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.myTags.length; i++) riot.mount(this.myTags[i].tag);
});
```